# Is there an kernel version list available somewhere?

Tags: kernel, versions

So, for dev needs, I need to find all available kernel versions for given ubuntu version, for example, Lucid Lynx server.

In short, something similar to this novell wiki for SLES:
http://wiki.novell.com/index.php/Kernel_versions

So, is there something like this, but for ubuntu? 
My google searches found absolutely nothing. :(

Comment: Something like [Ubuntu - Details of package linux-image in lucid](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/kernel/linux-image) maybe?

Comment: You can find the kernel source code at kernel.org. Ubuntu uses the source code from upstream + ubuntu patches. Unless you are an ubuntu developer, I am going to suggest, most of the time you are not going to be dealing with the ubuntu patches. If you have a problem with the original source code you would file at kernel.org. If you have a problem with an ubuntu patch you would file on launchpad

Answer (score 0):

I think the question itself is somewhat invalid, since you can compile any custom Linux kernel and use it with Ubuntu. For example, I'm renting a VPS running Saucy (13.10), which comes with the 3.11.x kernel by default, but my provider is using 2.6.32 so it's actually running on 2.6.32.

Anyway, [Wikipedia has a list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Table_of_versions) of the default kernels shipped with each version of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the [mainline kernel mapping](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/info/kernel-version-map.html) and also get the branch using [git](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/SourceCode)